# How to switch remote user in Capistrano

Tags: capistrano

In capistrano, I can set the `:user` variable to determine which user is logged to ssh, when executing remote commands. But I'd like to execute commands as different users depending on task. Is it possible? Something like `run "command", :as => "bob"` would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-DSL-Action-Invocation-Run

You could use combination of `:shell` and `&block`:

```
run "echo am i bob ? :$USER:", :shell => "su - bob -s bash" do |channel, stream, data|
  channel.send_data("#{bob_password}\n")
end
```